# The AlertDialog does not apper

Tags: android, eclipse, list, button, android-alertdialog

I have a TO-DO List and there is an AlertDialog that adds items to the ListView. On each item there is a Button (id: button1) when I click on the Button want a AlertDialog to apper. I have tried Different codes but i have not been able to figer out how to do it.

[image]

[image]

[image]

this is my code...

```
      button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
      dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this).create();
      dialog.setMessage("New list name");
      dialog.setButton("Rename", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        dialog.cancel();

    }
});
  dialog.setButton2("Delete", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        dialog.dismiss();

    }
});
  dialog.setButton3("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        dialog.cancel();

    }
});
  button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        dialog.show();

    }
});
```

So I want the more Button to make an AlertDialog appear.

Please Help.

Comment: Pictures are nice but please provide some code of  how you are creating and trying to show your `AlertDialog`

Comment: search for tutorials with custom dialog box..if you have any problems then u can come back

Comment: I dont know whats going on in your code but you should open the AlertDialog in you list's adapter when you click on the button in the getView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to implement a clickable button inside a listitem wiah is also a clickable area, android gets confused with it, please read this nice tutorial ;)

http://wiresareobsolete.com/wordpress/2011/08/clickable-zones-in-listview-items/

If, on the other hand the button is getting clicked, and the problem is actually in showing the dialog please make sure that you call dialog.show(); at the end ;)